# Reshaping data to fit a multivariate LSTM time series model with time distributed wrapper

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset comprising of hourly data from the past 7 years.

I am trying to use train to predict one variable (price) 24 hours in advance, based on 168 hours (1 week) of historic data for all variables, including price.

To do this I am attempting to build a NN with an LSTM layer and a time distributed layer, however am struggling to understand the shape coming of the data returning from each layer.

My code is as follows:

`X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_valid.shape, Y_valid.shape, X_test.shape, Y_test.shape`

```
((43800, 168, 6),
 (43800, 24),
 (8760, 168, 6),
 (8760, 24),
 (8574, 168, 6),
 (8574, 24))
```

So the training data (X) is made up of 43800 samples, looking back over 168 hours, for 6 features.
The Y is 43800 samples, prediction for every hour for 24 hours in advance. This is currently where I am in attempting to run the model

```
model8 = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.LSTM(10, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences = True),
    keras.layers.LSTM(20, return_sequences= True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(24))
])

model8.compile(loss="mape", optimizer="adam")
history = model8.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_26 to have shape (168, 24) but got array with shape (24, 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I don't fully understand why the time distributed layer expects all 168 hours of the past (with 24 features?), and not just the prediction of the future.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider *X_train.shape* and *Y_train.shape* in the first instance.

X_train.shape is structured as follows: **(samples, time steps, features)**.

Given *(43800, 168, 6)*, this means that:

- 43800 observations are being used to train the model
- There are 168 time steps in the model, i.e. steps back in time that the model uses to calibrate weight updates.
- There are 6 features in the model, i.e. each timestep in the model is comprised of six features.

Now, if you are specifying X_train to consider 168 timesteps, then the LSTM model expects that Y_train is comprised of 168 timesteps, i.e. Y_train takes the shape **(time steps, samples)**.

Your specification for Y_train is erroneous as it specifies **24** time steps with only **1** sample whereas the LSTM model is expecting 168 time steps with 24 samples, as was specified under X_train.

However many time steps you choose - they must be consistent across both X_train and Y_train. Hope this helps.